# Wordpress PasswordHash return always false

Tags: php, wordpress

I want check user password manualy

My code:

```
$x = '$P$ByGMEDnQJhSnHi2vhNXCSSijTo6AoT0';
$p = '13750955';
            
$wpHasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
$check = $wpHasher->CheckPassword($p, $x);
var_dump($check);
```

`$x` copied from wordpress database

`$check` return always `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a step:

```php
$x = '$P$ByGMEDnQJhSnHi2vhNXCSSijTo6AoT0';
$p = '13750955';
            
$wpHasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
$password = $wpHasher ->HashPassword($p);
$check = $wpHasher->CheckPassword($p, $x);
var_dump($check);
```